# Нужны кавычки для вопроса, нуждающегося в правке

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Наверное, из-за усталости не могу согласовать данную фразу под вопросом, нуждающимся в правке:

[image: странные слова]

Вероятно, замечание требуется как-то выделить.

Comment: Текста тут всегда бывает мало... Уже штуках в 5 вопросах это упоминается

Comment: Поправил опечатки («про» на «по» и «пользователями» на «участниками»).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPD: использовал второй вариант.

Эта строка собирается из двух: вводное  предложение и причина закрытия. Причина используется и сама по себе, так что проще было бы поменять так:

> Вопрос закрыт, так как необходимо..., пользователями...
>
> Вопрос закрыт по причине того, что необходимо..., пользователями...